# C: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)' to parameter of type 'char (*)[5]', but program works fine

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, warnings, incompatibility

I am getting the following warning:

warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)' to parameter of type 'char (*)[5]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
printField(field[5]);

The printField function looks like this:

```
void printField(char (*field)[5])
{
...
}
```

and the field I am giving to it is defined as follows:

```
char (*field) = get_field(input);
```

Here is the function call:

```
printField(field);
```

Now, I do understand, that there is obviously some sort of mismatch happening, but I can't tell what to change for it not to be there anymore. I would appreciate it very much, if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `get_field` return a pointer to the first element (character) of an array (null-terminated string), then that happens to be the same as the pointer to the array itself.

If we illustrate it with a simple array:

```
char s[5];
```

Then that will look something like this in memory (with pointers added):

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| s[0] | s[1] | s[2] | s[3] | s[4] |
+------+------+------+------+------+
^
|
&s[0]
|
&s
```

Now as can be seen that there are two pointers pointing to the same location: `&a[0]` and `&s`.

`&s[0]` is what using the array *decay* to, and it's the type `char *`.

`&s` is a pointer to the array itself, and have the type `char (*)[5]`.

When we apply it to your case, `field` is the first pointer, it points to the first element of an array. Which happens to be the same location as the pointer to the array itself which is what `printField` expects.

That's the reason it "works". But you should not do like that, you should fix the function to take an `char *` argument instead:

```
void printField(char *field);
```

Answer (score 0):

The types are different.

- `char *ptr;` declares the pointer to **`char`**
- `char (*ptr)[5];` declared the pointer to an **array of 5 characters**.

Those pointer types are not compatible - thus compiler warning.

In your case, both pointers refer to the same place in the memory (and that is the reason why the program works).